# scrlttr2 - change footheight on second page

Tags: scrlttr2, footer

Is it possible to move the footer on the second page in `scrlttr2` a bit down? The bottom margin in the screenshot (red line) seems very high.

The document looks much better when I switch of `footsepline` but I would like to use it.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[headsepline, footsepline, enlargefirstpage, firstfoot=false]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\pagestyle{headings}   % not necessary for this MWE
\setkomavar{fromname}{It is me}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{xxx}
\opening{Hello,}
\Blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Unfortunately, not. When I switch on `footsepline` the margin is much bigger than without the line in the footer. In your link `footsepline` is not active.

Comment: @Sveinung Where do I use the old package? I know the change and LaTeX throws warnings when using the old one. Ah, I see, you mean the pagestyle. I can remove this line for clarification.

Comment: You are not using the `footexclude` option, which reduces (a little bit) the height of the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `footsepline` sets automatically option `footinclude=true`. So maybe it is enough to add `footinclude=false` after `footsepline`.

```latex
\documentclass[headsepline, footsepline, enlargefirstpage, firstfoot=false,
  footinclude=false% <- added
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\pagestyle{headings}   % not necessary for this MWE
\setkomavar{fromname}{It is me}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{xxx}
\opening{Hello,}
\Blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you should remove option `enlargefirstpage` (see the comment of @Sveinung):

```latex
\documentclass[headsepline, footsepline, 
  %enlargefirstpage,% <- remove this
  firstfoot=false,
  footinclude=false% <- added
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\pagestyle{headings}   % not necessary for this MWE
\setkomavar{fromname}{It is me}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{xxx}
\opening{Hello,}
\Blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `footinclude=false` equivalent to `footexclude`?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin `footexclude` is an obsolete option. There would be a warning this option would be replaced by `footinclude=false,version=first,enabledeprecatedfontcommands` and this will result in an additional warning. So it is really better to use `footinclude=false`. See also the KOMA-Script documentation.

Comment: thanks! for pointing that out :)

Comment: @esdd First page looks awful. Too much text at the bottom of the page :)

Comment: @Sveinung You are right. The OP should remove option `enlargefirstpage`.